# How to have Eclipse automatically open/preview files as I select them in Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to have Eclipse automatically open/preview files as I select them in Project Explorer? I know I can double-click, but I want to quickly arrow up/down as I explore a project.

I am essentially looking for something like Mac Finder's Quick Look or Windows 7 Explorer's Preview Pane. IntelliJ IDEA has this functionality also and calls it "Autoscroll to Source".

Eclipse has "Link to Editor" but that works the reverse of what I want (what IntelliJ IDEA calls "Autoscroll from Source") - it updates the Project Explorer from the editor. I want the editor to update from the Project Explorer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Open Mode (single click)
```

This option open new source file in new editor tab. To disable this, and keep only one active editor tab, use:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> 
Select checkbox 'Close editors automatically' -> 
Set 'Number of opened editors before closing' to 1
```

Comment: I think this will open the full editor instead of the requested preview, but this is as close as you can get.

Comment: Yes, but exactly what I expected if there was a way to do it. Thanks! Bummer they don't have it as a toolbar icon like IntelliJ.

Comment: But this approach closes all the other already opened editors, which is undesired...

Answer (score 7):

I think combining mishadoff's suggestion of single click open mode with "Open when using arrow keys" exactly answers OP's question:

```
Window(or Eclipse on Mac) -> Preferences -> General:
```

[image]

(I am using Juno version)